# matplotlib bar plot spacings

Tags: matplotlib, formatting, bar-chart

I'm trying to plot 3 bars per value of N. The data is:

```
N=['A','B','C','D','E','F']
SF = (0.87,9.4,49,110,820,1752)
IRT = (0.34,25,210,487,2861,5541)
IRTO = (0.5,33,271,568,3031,6314)
```

These numbers of w (width), y_pos and figsize are basically just trial and error until it looks decent enough to my eye...

```
w = 1
y_pos = 4*np.arange(len(N))

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,5))  
rects1 = ax.bar(y_pos - w, SF, align='center', alpha=0.7, width=w, color="lightgrey", log=True)
rects2 = ax.bar(y_pos , IRT, align='center', alpha=1.0, width=w, color="grey", log=True)
rects3 = ax.bar(y_pos + w, IRTO, align='center', alpha=1.0, width=w, color="black", log=True) 

plt.xticks(y_pos,N,fontsize=13)
    
legend = ax.legend((rects1[0], rects2[0], rects3[0]), ('SF', 'IRT', 'IRTO'), loc='upper left')

plt.show()
```

All that produces the following plot:

[image]

This is pretty good, unfortunately I like to to make everything as perfect as possible so I want to do basically 4 thins:

1. reduce the space between the left axis and the first bar (and the last bar and the right axis).
2. increase the size of the top axis so that the highest bar is not as close to it
3. remove the middle ticks over the lower axis
4. add the blue ticks (between the bars) - see figure below:

[image]

I really tried to do this, but I couldnt find a way to do it yet.
I was able to do number 3 alone, but not number 4.

Thanks!

Comment: Managed to remove the spaces over the x axis with `plt.margins(x=0.04)`
and to increase the limit of the top axis with `plt.ylim(ymax=15000)`. Fighting with the ticks now...